# Restoring 64GB iPhone 6 from iTunes Backup - low disk space

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, backup, itunes, iphone

I need help restoring my iPhone. My computer is saying its disk space is too low, even though there is more than enough gigs space on my computer than the actual backup file size, which is 6GB.

So, I signed into my iTunes account on my friend's computer. I copied my backup file for my iPhone from the `%appsdata%/Apple Computer/Backups` folder on my computer to a USB stick.

Then, I put it in the same folder on my friend's computer (like it was on mine). This was supposed to be so iTunes on her computer, signed into my account, would recognize my backup file on her computer.

iTunes shows as if it knows the backup file is there (like I hoped it would, just like on my computer). So, I tried to restore my phone from that backup that is now on her computer by plugging my phone into her computer.

iTunes pulls up the window that shows its processing the backup file to begin and give an estimated time frame. Suddenly, it stops and pulls up another window now saying the backup does not exist.

Am I missing something?

My computer keeps telling my disk space is too low. However, it doesn't seem to be accomplishing anything, no matter how much I have cleared off so far. It still says it can't restore my phone, because there isn't enough space, hence trying to do it on my friend's computer. However, like I said, the backup is only 6GB and there is much more space than that available on my computer, it says.

So why won't it work? Or why does the second option, her computer, tell me my backup doesn't exist on her's, even though iTunes shows it does? Why won't it let me restore my phone on her's?

I've been wrestling with this for two days now, following forum advice I can find, trying different creative options like my friend's computer and nothing so far is working! The whole reason I did this in the first place, is because Rogers told me I needed to, in order to fix the software glitches I had prior to this bigger problem now. So much for that!

Now what do I do? Is my backup just gone now and I have to start over on my iPhone without it? Or can one of you help me get my backup back on my phone?